# Unity Profiler - What would cause PlayerEndOfFrame to have 10-16MB in GC Alloc?

Tags: unity, optimization, memory-efficiency, profiler

I can't find much documentation on what "PlayerEndOfFrame" does. Sure it is the end of a frame but what would cause the GC Alloc to go so high?

This is the profiler results from a debug build on a remote machine using the IP connect to unity profiler.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PlayerEndOfFrame is where your work shows up when you run a Unity coroutine and increment it by using the command "yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();"

In this case the coroutine you are running is instantiating a lot of memory and doing a lot of work every frame.

It is also worth noting that by using WaitForEndOfFrame here you are running your coroutine after all the other processing for that frame has finished. This is not normally a good idea. Most of the time you should be progressing to the next frame using the statement "yield return null;", which will run your coroutine in the normal update loop.

You probably won't notice any difference when using WaitForEndOfFrame most of the time, but it will cause some weird graphical issues if your framerate drops or when you initialize a game object in one section of your code and then set it's values in a different section.